# printing the sum of unique numbers

Tags: python

I'd like this to print the answer "15" but I'm not sure how I would go about this exactly, I'd like the list to work for any set of numbers so that "int(input()) would work.

here is my code so far:

```
x = [5,1,2,3,4,5]
xs = [x for i in range(x)]
print(sum([xs[i] for i in range(len(xs))
  if xs[i] not in xs[:i] + xs[i + 1:]]))
```

Comment: `print(sum(set(x)))` ?

Answer (score 2):

just sum the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) of your list:

```
sum(set(x))
```

`set` will (efficiently) remove the duplicates for you.

if you `input` the elements to sum; you'd need to convert the string you get to  a list of integers; e.g.;

```
inp = input() # e.g. '1,2,3,4,5'
x = [int(i) for i in inp.split(',')]
# or directly remove the duplicates:
x = set(int(i) for i in inp.split(','))
```

just `int(input())` will not work because you will not get a list directly; something like `[int(i) for i in input()]` might but is not great design...

it all depends of what you want as input.

Comment: The original question ask:                                                              
                                                                                                       
Write a Python program that reads an integer that gives the number of integers to be read and then reads these integers, one per line, into a list. Print the total of these integers except that if an integer appears more than once it will not be counted. You may not use the count method of lists. For example, the input:  5 1 2 3 4 5 would give 15

Comment: The correct response is xs = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))] print(sum([xs[i] for i in range(len(xs)) \ if xs[i] not in xs[:i] + xs[i + 1:]])

Comment: However I was wondering if with your set method it stays the same or you have to create a set to input like so:x = int(input)
xs=set()
for x in range(x):
    xs.append(x)
print(sum(set(xs)))

Comment: ...what is your desired user input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use set to create a unique list.

```
x = [5,1,2,3,4,5]
set(x)
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

And you can sum it

```
sum(set(x))
```

> 15